# jzy3d display issue in RCP Netbean

Tags: charts, netbeans-7, jogl, jzy3d

I have upgrade jzyv8 to v9 in my Netbean application. 
But I cannot resize/maximize Jpanel/frame using Jzy3d v9 with Jogl 2, i got blank screen after resize panel and if i dig into code view object is null in the Render3d object.

GJPanel dispose the renderer.

```
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable canvas, int x, int y, int width, int height){
    //System.err.println("reshape with " + width + " " + height);
    this.width  = width;
    this.height = height;

    if(view != null){
        view.dimensionDirty = true;

        if(canvas!=null){
            //GL gl1 = canvas.getGL();
            GL2 gl = canvas.getGL().getGL2();
            view.clear(gl);
            view.render(gl, glu);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with `jogl-all-main 2.0-rc11` and NetBeans 7.3. Any progress with that issue?

Answer (score 0):

using NEWT toolkit instead of AWT solved the issue for me:

```
Chart chart = new Chart(Quality.Advanced, "newt");
```